# Fetch data from mysql with autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to get data from mySQL database without refreshing my page. To get the data from the user I am using a livesearch also from the same database. When I press the button I want to show the data of the line in the database that the user has inputed. My problem is with the php, when I press the button to output the encoded result, the output is "null" and I cannot see why it says this because I am fetching the values from the database.

An early thank you for your help :)

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<h1>LIVE SEARCH WITH AJAX TEST</h1>
<div class="ui-widget">
   <label for="recherche">Recherche: </label>
   <input id="recherche" name="recherche">
   <button name="button" id="button">OK</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="namedata"></div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        var recherche = $('#recherche').val();
        if ($.trim(recherche) != ''){
            $.post('getvalue.php', {recherche: recherche}, function(data){
                $('#namedata').text(data);
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['recherche']) === true && empty($_POST['recherche']) === false) {
    require 'connect.php'; 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT capacityingo FROM smartphone WHERE name ='" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['recherche'])) . "' "); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You should also dump the result in PHP and console log the response (data) to see what it looks like. You're currently treating the response like a string, when it isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error was in your PHP script, although, since I have PHP7.1, I couldn't test it to see where the bug was.
I hope this code works for you. I added error handling, since your code lacked it whole.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['recherche']))
{
    if (empty($_POST['recherche']))
    {
        exit();
    }

    //sanitize string entering db
    $recherche = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'recherche', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $recherche = filter_var($recherche, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    //mysqli connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

    //statement with FALSE return error handling
    if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT capacityingo FROM smartphone WHERE name = ?"))
    {
        //throw error
        // trigger_error('The statement could not be prepared', E_USER_ERROR);
        //or (to be readable by javascript)
        $error = array
            (
                'error' => 'The statement could not be prepared'
            );

        echo json_encode($error);
        exit();
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $recherche);

    //execute with error handling
    if (!$stmt->execute())
    {
        //throw error
        // trigger_error('The statement could not be executed', E_USER_ERROR);
        //or (to be readable by javascript)
        $error = array
            (
                'error' => 'The statement could not be executed'
            );

        echo json_encode($error);
        exit();
    }

    //make statement output to result
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = array();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        //add each result to an array
        $data[] = $row;
        //if this does not work try
        // array_push ($data, $row);
    }
    //print the array encoded in JSON
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to make an autocomplete search box you should consider the "autocomplete" part as everytime a user types something in the search box it updates. Something like this in your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#recherche').on('input', function(){ /* in place of your button i put your input and checked for it's update - and don't forget to make a copy of this for your search button too, I don't wanna make this update too long */
        var recherche = $('#recherche').val();
        if ($.trim(recherche) != ''){
            $.post('search.php', {'recherche': recherche}, function(data){
                $('#namedata').text(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Also for a search system you shouldn't use the `=` operator in your statement. You should use the `SQL` `LIKE` operator and put your search query in PHP like this:

```
$recherche = '%'. $recherche .'%';
```

After all sanitizing and escaping characters from above the `SQL` statement.